# How can I get the selected value in a drop-down list using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a new learner of web crawling, and I have encountered a problem of getting the selected value in a drop-down list. I am currently using beautifulsoup to try to solve my problem.

The source was like:

```
<TDalign="right">投资方式:   


    </TD>
<TD>

<SELECT name="financingType">

<OPTION selected="selected"value="48">增资扩股</OPTION>
<OPTION value="211">股权受让</OPTION>
<OPTION value="212">增资+受让</OPTION>
<OPTION value="771">CB</OPTION>
<OPTION value="772">担保</OPTION>

</SELECT>
```

for this case, I want to get the text marked with value tag "48" (the selected option),that is, "增资扩股".

Honestly, I don't have any idea of this. I have tried：

```
financingType = soup.find('select',{'name': 'financingType'}).get('value')
```

but it gives a `NONE` value.

I would like to ask through what methods can I get the selected value of this dropdown list?

The problem is that I have many attributes of these "dropdown" type, for example, in this case, I have . And I would like to ask how could I spot this specific attribute of "financingType"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: there are missing spaces in your source, is that intended or just a typo?

Comment: I want to make the source more readable so... does that matter?

Answer (score 2):

Use css selector which is much faster to fetch the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<TDalign="right">投资方式:   


    </TD>
<TD>

<SELECT name="financingType">

<OPTION selected="selected" value="48">增资扩股</OPTION>
<OPTION value="211">股权受让</OPTION>
<OPTION value="212">增资+受让</OPTION>
<OPTION value="771">CB</OPTION>
<OPTION value="772">担保</OPTION>

</SELECT>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('option[selected="selected"]')['value'])
print(soup.select_one('option[selected="selected"]').text)
```

### Printed on console:

```
    48
增资扩股
```

**EDITED**

```
print(soup.select_one('select[name="financingType"]').select_one('option[selected="selected"]').text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is that we have many attributes of these "dropdown" type, for example, in this case, I have <SELECTname="financingType">. And I would like to ask how could I spot this specific attribute of "financingType"?

Comment: @toyhtoza : check the edited answer is that you are after?

Comment: @toyhtoza : Glad to help you.can you accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: That whole thing could be reduced into soup.select_one('[name="financingType"] [selected="selected"]'").text   Simply have a descendant combinator between parent select and child option (which you specify via selected attribute/)

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the selected `option` tag with `soup.find`, specifying the value of the `selected` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
result = soup(html, 'html.parser').find('select', {'name':'financingType'}).find('option', {'selected':'selected'})['value']
```

Output:

```
'48'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is that we have many attributes of these "dropdown" type, for example, in this case, I have <SELECTname="financingType">. And I would like to ask how could I spot this specific attribute of "financingType"?

Comment: @toyhtoza Please see my recent edit. The new solution will anchor the `option` search on the `bs4` `select` object that has the `name` attribute of `'financingType'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this rather easily with `mechanicalsoup` 
The solution would look something like that

```
import mechanicalsoup
bro = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
bro.open(url)
bro.select_form(f'form[action={action_name}]')
bro["financingType"] = "48"
```

You will need to find the form action in the html and set it to a variable `action_name`